# how to replace %xxx to be $xxx in string?

Tags: php, regex

how to replace %xxx to be $xxx in string ?

```
<?php
// how to replace the %xxx to be $xxx

define('A',"what are %a doing, how old are %xx ");
$a='hello';
$xx= 'jimmy';
$b= preg_replace("@%([^\s])@","${$1}",A);   //error here;

// should output: what are hello doing,how old are jimmy
echo $b;
```

?>

Comment: I don't know if this will work, but `"\${$1}"` might work?

Comment: @Class That will work to get `$` in the string, but it won't evaluate the variables (i.e. `$a` in the string should evaluate to `hello`).

Comment: **Don't say "I got an error". Always say "Here is the error I got" and then show us the exact error.** Don't paraphrase it. Don't retype it. Cut & paste the error message exactly from your screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to evaluate the replacement value as php, so you need the `e` modifier (although it seems it is deprecated as of php 5.5...). You also need a quantifier as `$xx` contains more than one character:

```
$b= preg_replace('@%([^\s]+)@e','${$1}',A);
                          ^  ^
```

See the [working example on codepad](http://codepad.org/P2GpOYmW).

By the way, I prefer single quotes to avoid problems with php trying to look for variables.

Comment: `/regex/` looks better. Especially when there are no `\` symbols in regex.

Answer (score 1):

In order to incorporate variables in this manner, you should probably do something like this:

```
$b = preg_replace_callback("/(?<=%)\w+/",function($m) {
        return $GLOBALS[$m[0]];
    },A);
```

Note, however, that using `$GLOBALS` is generally a bad idea. Ideally, you should have something like this:

```
$replacements = array(
    "%a"=>"hello",
    "%xx"=>"jimmy"
);
$b = strtr(A,$replacements);
```